# Image Load from SQL Server 2008 to PictureBox fails

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble to read an image from a SQL Server 2008 database and load it in Windows Forms `PictureBox`. This is the code to retrieve image from DB:

```
//UI Button Binded Code
private void LoadImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   DataSet data = DBClient.GetEmployee(_EID[0]);
   //...
   //...
   byte[] pic = (byte[])data.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Picture"];

   EmployeeCardForm ef = new EmployeeCardForm(name, fname, nic, deptt, desig, doj, address, ecode, pic);
   ef.Show();
}

 //EmployeeCardForm Constructor File Code
 public EmployeeCardForm(String name, String fname, String nic, String deptt, String desig, String doj, String address, String ecode, byte[] pic)
 {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.MaximizeBox = false;
        label18.Text = "Record has been successfully Saved. Please take Print out by pressing Print Button below!";
        try
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(pic));
            //Some code here
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Some Error occurred!");
        }
        //declare event handler for printing in constructor
        printdoc1.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(printdoc1_PrintPage);
    }
```

When I run this program and click on the button to load image the application became unresponsive. After debugging I came to know that the following line of code has problem:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(pic));
```

And when I used try/catch block, it showed me following exception:
`System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid. at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData) at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream) at SimpleReport.EmployeeCardForm..ctor(String name, String fname, String nic, String deptt, String desig, String doj, String address, String ecode, Byte[] pic) in D:\O Projects\EM\SimpleReport\EmployeeCardForm.cs:line 60`

This is how i am saving image into DB:

```
private void SaveImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Picture_Path= filename;
     FileStream fs;
     fs = new FileStream(@Picture_Path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
     //a byte array to read the image
     byte[] picbyte = new byte[fs.Length];
     fs.Read(picbyte, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
     fs.Close();
     DBClient.AddEmployee(ecode, emp_name.Text, fname, nic, deptt, desig, doj, address, picbyte);
}
```

Please help me out!

Comment: Stops on that line and never gets pass, no errors?

Comment: yes it hangs on the above line and program crashes!!!

Comment: is there any data in the pic variable?

Comment: what do you mean crashes? Any exception? try to change IOException to Exception in your catch block, maybe you'll be able to catch specific exception.

Comment: your code should work OK, maybe there is a problem with this paraticular picture, did you try to save it to the disk and see if it is OK ?

Comment: Yes it has the value: pic = {byte[13]}. Its an byte array with 13 elements in it containing some numbers (most probably the image binary format)

Comment: have you tried to change exception type? Possibly  you getting ArgumentException.

Comment: @Reniuz I have changed IOException to Exception and I catched following exception:
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream, Boolean useEmbeddedColorManagement, Boolean validateImageData)
   at System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(Stream stream)
   at SimpleReport.EmployeeCardForm..ctor(String name, String fname, String nic, String deptt, String desig, String doj, String address, String ecode, Byte[] pic) in D:\O Projects\EM\SimpleReport\EmployeeCardForm.cs:line 60

Comment: please add this exception to your question...then it is better readable

Comment: @webber2k6 I have put the exception in question statement.

Comment: Like I said you getting ArgumentException and from [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) you can see that `The stream does not have a valid image format`. Also I cant imagine image from 13bytes :) So you need to have _correct binary image data in database first_

Comment: @Reniuz I have added code which is saving image into DB.

Comment: First you converting fs.Length(its of type int64) to int32 - its not good you may "cut" part of picture data or you need to read it in chunks using loop. The ease way to read bytes from file is to use [File.ReadAllBytes("YourPicturePathHere");](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) function.

Comment: @Reniuz It is not working: byte[] picbyte = new byte[0];
                picbyte = File.ReadAllBytes(Picture_Path);

Answer (score 5):

After some chat the issue was that picture binaries are stored in database in incorrect format. It might be several problems:

1. Incorrect type/size of table field.
2. Incorrect byte reading

First check if you have `varbinary(max)` type\size of datatable field.

Second - here is how you can read all bytes of file:

```
private void SaveImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] allFileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename); 
    DBClient.AddEmployee(ecode, emp_name.Text, fname, nic, deptt, desig, doj, address, allFileBytes);
}
```

Comment: almost +1 ;)  please add context, without looking at the comments it looks like your answer has nothing to do with question

Comment: @Reniuz Same result, It always stored the image into DB with following data:
0x53797374656D2E427974655B5D

Comment: @Antonio Bakula atleast Reniuz is helping me out here. You are just sitting to waste the SO comments boxes.

Comment: @NidaSulheri it's for future googlers,  to quote Jeff Atwood: "Ultimate intent of SO is Collectively increasing the sum total of good programming knowledge in the world".

Comment: @Antonio Bakula you are only wasting my time here!!!

Comment: Antonio you are right. I just posted first that Nida could check what shes got.